# Kotlin выпадающий список вставить и получить id выбранного элемента

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview

Xml:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:text=""
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            android:textSize="20sp" 
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
 tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"/>
```

Дальше делаю запрос к Api сайта

```
val inventory =
            createRequest("http:\\www.ru")
                .map { Gson().fromJson(it, FeedAPI::class.java) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

        request = inventory.subscribe({
            showLianerLayout(it.data)
        }, {

        })
```

Классы имеют такой вид

```
class FeedAPI(
    val data: ArrayList<FeedItemAPI>
)
class FeedItemAPI(
    val id: String,
    val name: String
)
```

и получаю элементы вида

```
[{"name":"text","id":"1"},{"name":"text2","id":"2"}]
```

Вызываемая функция при вставке элементов в выпадающий список имеет вид

```
fun showLianerLayout(feedList: ArrayList<FeedItemAPI>) {
        val list: List<String>
        list = ArrayList()

        for (f in feedList) {
            list.add(f.name);
        }

        val aa = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list)
        this.txtSpinnerValue.setThreshold(1)
        this.txtSpinnerValue.setAdapter(aa);
}
```

Как мне при вставке хранить еще и соответствующий id? И при выборе получать именно его?

Comment: в адаптер принимайте не string a ArrayList<FeedItemApi>

Comment: Как тогда адаптер поймет что в выпадающем списке нужно name выводить, а id получать только при выборе?

Comment: Приведите код вашего адаптера,я покажу как

Comment: Использую какой-то дефолтный android.widget.ArrayAdapter

Comment: Сделайте потомка от `ArrayAdapter`, переопределите `getView` и все. Тут есть пример: https://medium.com/@sankalpchauhan.me/creating-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-a-user-defined-arraylist-in-android-e076d0064d0d

Comment: Для меня не самый очевидный пример) Абсолютно не понимаю как его свести со своим кодом. Как расширить адаптер и переопределить getView.